# My raycast is not detecting objects properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to create a CameraFollow script for a 2.5d game where the camera follows the player with a tilted 60 degree angle, but when the player is hidden behind a wall the camera uses an eagle view of 90 degrees. For doing that Im doing a raycast from the camera to the player, with the exact distance from the camera to the player. If there is a collision it takes the eagle view, if not it uses the normal view. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float distance = 10;
    private Vector3 offset;
    private Vector3 eagle_offset;

    public Transform target;

    public float smoothSpeed = 5.0f;


    void Start() {
        offset = new Vector3(0.0f, 1.5f, -1.0f).normalized * distance;
        eagle_offset = new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f).normalized * distance;
    }


    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset; 
        Vector3 smoothedPosition;
        RaycastHit hit;
        
        Vector3 direction = (desiredPosition - target.position).normalized;
        
        if (Physics.Raycast(desiredPosition, direction, out hit, distance)) {
            smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target.position + eagle_offset, Time.deltaTime * smoothSpeed );  
        }

        else {
            smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, Time.deltaTime * smoothSpeed);
        }

        transform.position = smoothedPosition;
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay first, pet peeve of mine is lerp. Lerp is a linear interpolation, from first to second argument, with the third argument being a value between 0 and 1 that determines the "blend" between the first argument (0) and the second (1).

If you're getting camera jitter then you're probably using physics and the issue there is that physics updates on FixedUpdate, which put should very rarely coincide with Update.

To your question, if we look at the following definition:

```
Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
```

and then look at the following:

```
Vector3 direction = (desiredPosition - target.position).normalized;
```

then you can see that direction is (target position + offset) - target position, meaning your "direction" is just equal to the offset.

So, a couple notes here.

1. If you're trying to raycast from the camera to the target, I'd suggest using `transform.LookAt(target);` FIRST and then you can just use `transform.forward` as the direction. The `transform.position` would be the origin or "from" in the raycast command.
2. I'd suggest having this script on one camera and having a second camera as the "eagle" view. Consider the case where there IS an obstruction - your raycast detects the hit and flips to an eagle view, where there is no obstruction, so then you flip back to normal view, and it's still obstructed, so it flips back, etc. If you have two cameras then you can just raycast from the main camera every frame and, if it's obstructed, you just disable the main camera and enable the eagle camera, and if it's not obstructed then you do the opposite.